# Modify regex to filter input containing certain strings

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `/href=('|")(\w+|\/dashboard)/` that matches every HTML anchor that has an href that starts with `/dashboard`, or `something/without/a/slash/at/the/beginning`.

So this regex matches:

```
<a href="/dashboard/security-settings"></a>
<a href='dashboard/security-settings'></a>
<a href='something/security-settings'></a>
```

But not:

```
<a href="/home"></a>
<a href="/about"></a>
```

The issue here is that it also matches:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<a href="www.facebook.com"></a>
```

How can I filter href's starting with `http` or `www` from the regex? I tried playing with the `^` operator with no luck:

```
href=('|")(([^http][^www]|\w+)|\/dashboard)
```

Comment: which language?...why use regex?use an html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` within a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) works on individual letters, not strings. So `[^http]` actually means "Match one character that's neither an `h` nor a `t` nor a `p`".

You need a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

```
href=(['"])(?!http|www)(\w+|/dashboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
/^href=['"](\w+|\/dashboard)/
```

The `^` operator (if used at the start of the regexp) makes sure that the regexp is only matched at the beginning of the line, so it only matches strings that begin with `href`.

As others have mentioned you can use *negative lookahead* to explicitly filter out strings that begin with `http` or `www`. However, if the string would start with `ftp://` (or any prefix other than "http" or "www") it would still be matched using negative lookahead for "http" and "www". It seems better to use a white list in this case rather than a black list containing everything that you don't want to match.